# Woocommerce Checkout add remove coupon based on country

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to programmatically add/remove a coupon based on the selected country in the checkout. After looking around SO, I have this code which is working but:

1: For the code to run and the coupon to show/hide in the order summary I have to use `add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', ...)` and I need to trigger `update_checkout`. If I use another action the coupon will not show/hide.

2: If I try to print a message eg. *coupon applied* it will show in the `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping` section instead of on the top of the checkout form (obviously).

The code is

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'country_based_discount' );



function country_based_discount() {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
       return;
           
    $coupon_code = 'code';
    $allowed_countries = array('FR');
    
    $is_coupon_applied = WC()->cart->has_discount( $coupon_code  );
    $country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $is_country_allowed = in_array( $country, $allowed_countries );
    
    if( ! $is_coupon_applied && $is_country_allowed ) {
        WC()->cart->apply_coupon( $coupon_code );
        ?><script>jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');</script><?php
        printf('<div class="coupon-applied"> Free shipping offer applied! </div>');
    }
    elseif( $is_coupon_applied && ! $is_country_allowed ) {
        WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
        ?><script>jQuery(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');</script><?php
        WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
    } 

}
```

Can someone help me fix it please?